# Where does KVM hypervisor store VM files?

Tags: files, kvm, virsh

For a guest machine how can I know where the files created in vm (not the VM config files but actual files which I create while using VM) are stored on my host machine? To which directory of my host the root directory of VM is mapped?

Comment: They are stored inside the VM's containing filesystem.

Comment: which might be a raw or qcow2 etc file on the kvm host server (by default, in `/var/lib/libvirt/images` if you use `libvirt`) , or a disk partition or lvm volume, or a zfs zvol, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can see it from Storage tab in virt-manager.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To get the information from the command line (as root):

1. Determine the domain name you want to check:

> ```
> # virsh list --all
>  Id   Name          State
> ------------------------------
>  -    lab_master1   shut off
>  -    lab_worker1   shut off
>  -    lab_worker2   shut off
>  -    rhel9.2       shut off
> ```

2. Get the file(s) location information from domain '**rhel9.2**':

> ```
> # virsh domstats rhel9.2 | grep path
>   block.0.path=/var/lib/libvirt/images/rhel9.2.qcow2
> ```