# Any way to make Virtual Machine (e.g. KVM) use overlayfs like system to have main set of file(s) and additons separately?

Tags: virtual-machine, kvm, overlayfs

I've web searched, read [Where does KVM hypervisor store VM files?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/241601/where-does-kvm-hypervisor-store-vm-files) and consider my idea not doable by standard means, still maybe it is or can somebody advice some trick/workaround?

I want to have main VM file(s) of say installed Windows in KVM (or other VM if you know how to do below for other but not KVM), store it as "lower"/"main" set of files and be able to add programs to it by storing all additions/changes in file system in separate location in "upper" (like Linux overlayfs). TIA

That would allow to store many similar but different installations of client system in much more compact way.

Comment: Maybe you should reconsider your main os and think about Solaris and zones. This is how they work :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use copy-on-write disk images to get something like what you want.

Let's assume we have a disk image `windows-base.img`. We'd like to use this as the "lower" image, and create multiple "upper" clones from it so we can create multiple virtual machines that start with the same base configuration.

If you're working with `libvirt` under Linux, you can do something like this:

```
virt-install --disk pool=default,size=40,backing_store=windows-base.img,backing_format=raw ...
```

The `backing_store` option creates a new copy-on-write clone of the named image. Initially, this will have the same content as `windows-base.img` and will consume effectively zero space, but it will grow over time as the virtual machine modifies disk blocks.

[This article](https://fabianlee.org/2018/09/24/kvm-implementing-linked-clones-with-a-backing-file/) explores the process in more detail.

---

If you're *not* using `libvirt` (e.g., if you're running `qemu` directly), you can do the same thing manually using `qemu-img`; that looks something like:

```
qemu-img create -F raw -b windows-base.img -f qcow2 windows-1.qcow2 40g
```

Comment: hi again. When I use `virt-install` newly created clone starts to configure hardware (why? I guess KVM supplies different hardware config, I've created base image via GUI) and somehow arrives at non-operational network. I understand I need to clone VM (that is copy VM hardware settings). Do you know how to achieve it w/out direct edit of xml files? (I'm not sure editing in /etc would help either - not tried). TIA

Comment: I'm not entirely clear on the what you're asking. Can you open a new question that includes a specific example of what's going on? That might be easier than try to address this in comments.

Comment: I've created new question. I now see It is unrelated to COW, however please have a look, I got no feedback for a day already on that. TIA https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/713306/qemu-kvm-qemu-system-vm-has-no-network-connection-could-not-obtain-ip-addr